# Fantasy novel about a man trying to escape from mafia types in upstate New York woods

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this about 20 years ago (90's or maybe late 80's). The main protagonist is a guy trying to get away from organised criminals. He moves to upstate New York (I think) to live in the woods and begins to experience strange goings on with Pan like supernatural beings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds to me like Charles DeLint's [*Greenmantle*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/186423.Greenmantle) from 1988, his second book. The protagonist was a former hit man trying to retire. He falls for his neighbor (who is being stalked by her ex-) and winds up getting involved in the mysteries of the deep woods.

> Not far from the city there is an ancient wood, forgotten by the modern world, where Mystery walks in the moonlight. He wears the shape of a stag, or a goat, or a horned man wearing a cloak of leaves. He is summoned by the music of the pipes or a fire of bones on Midsummer's Evening. He is chased by the hunt and shadowed by the wild girl.

[image: Greenmantle front cover]

Several of the reviewers at Goodreads mention the mafia content (~1/2 the book) as well as the frequent use of the term "fercrissakes", which might be memorable to you.

Comment: I’ve added a summary from Goodreads and the summary from there. I tried adding the front cover image but I can’t seem to copy the larger image on my phone.

Comment: That's it! As soon as I saw the title and cover it came back to me. Thanks very much.

Comment: Thanks, Carrot! Good edits, much appreciated.

Comment: Glad to hear it, Tim! De Lint has a great storytelling style, he's in my Canadian SF Top Ten (along with Robinson, Huff, Harrison, Hughes...).